# sed or awk to replace string between pattern (convert absolute path to relative)

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to replace all folders in a path with ".."
This is part of a bigger script that will eventually replace some absolute paths into relative paths.

The expected output should look like this:

```
/ABCDdasda234sEA/asdas2das/asdasf34234/ => /../../../
/ABCDdasda234sEA/asdas2das/asdasf34234/124551assdfa/ => /../../../../
```

I tried various regex but couldn't get to match correctly, because last "/" is considered ending of the string instead of matching multiple times:

```
[root@test]# sed "s/^\/.*\/$/\/..\//g" <<< "/ABCDdasda234sEA/asdasdas/asdasf34234/"

/../
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The `.*` will eat everything including the following slashes, so use `[^/]*` instead (any number of characters except for the slash)

2) To avoid the `\+` (for "one or more occurences") which is not available in all `sed` version simply add a dot requiring at least one character. You don't need another `[^/]` here if you trust that there is no `//`

3) Just for beautification: If the pattern or replacement contain a slash, it's easier to read if you use a different delimiter for the `s` command like `_` or `#`

All together:

```
sed 's_/.[^/]*_/.._g'
```

Comment: Thank you. https://giphy.com/gifs/the-office-thank-you-michael-scott-1Z02vuppxP1Pa

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (length($i)) $i = ".."}1' <<END
/ABCDdasda234sEA/asdas2das/asdasf34234/
/ABCDdasda234sEA/asdas2das/asdasf34234/124551assdfa/
END
```

```
/../../../
/../../../../
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I also posted 2 more methods i found meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

I found two more methods meanwhile:

```
sed 's:/[[:alnum:]]*:../:g' <<< "/ABCDdasda234sEA/asdasdas/asdasf34234/42346346346/" | sed 's:^..::g'


awk -F'/' '{for( i = 2; i <= NF-1; i++ ) printf "/../" }' <<< "/ABCDdasda234sEA/asdasdas/asdasf34234/asfasddfg/2345555/"  | sed 's/\/\//\//g'
```

Also to include other special characters such as "_":

```
sed 's:/[[:alnum:]_]*:../:g' <<< "/ABCDdasda234sEA/asdasdas/asdasf34234/42346346$346/" | sed 's:^..::g'
```

Comment: Simply include everything but the slash: `sed 's_/.[^/]*_/.._g'`

Comment: nice, this is elegant. you should post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of *sed* do not accept the advanced features of regular expressions (e.g. **+** or **{}**) by default.  On my system, **\+** works ok.

Also, you may replace **\w** here with **[^/]**, since file names may contain blanks.